# Ajax: How to send 'empty' file using FormData and jQuery and get it in $_FILES

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have html form and want send file 'myfile' with Ajax and jQuery:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myfile" id="myfile">
</form>
```

My javascript code:

```
function getFile(fieldName){
    var itemValue = $('input[name="' + fieldName + '"]')[0].files[0];
    return itemValue;
}

function sendFile(){
    var formaData = new FormData();
    var itemName = 'myfile';
    var itemValue = getFile(itemName);
    formaData.append(itemName, itemValue);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: formaData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
    });
}
```

All works fine when file is choosen. I have in the server $_FILES global array and data in it which got via Ajax:

```
["myfile"]=>
    array(5) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(13) "file_name.jpg"
        ["type"]=>
        string(10) "image/jpeg"
        ["tmp_name"]=>
        string(14) "/tmp/phpefJlk3"
        ["error"]=>
        int(0)
        ["size"]=>
        int(344100)
    }
```

The problem when file is not choosen!
When I don't choose any file and send Ajax request then I have empty $_FILES, but I have $_POST with field 'myfile' equals 'undefined'. But I need 'myfile' field in $_FILES even it is empty. I want something like:

```
["myfile"]=>
    array(5) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["type"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["tmp_name"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["error"]=>
        int(4)
        ["size"]=>
        int(0)
    }
```

Above is what I have in $_FILES globall array if I send empty form without Ajax. I want the same if I using Ajax. Is it posssible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling files with AJAX is not that simple. It comes up with a lot of problems due to different clients, hugh files and all that stuff. (As you can see in your "simple"-Error here =) In your case, no file is selected so there is no need to send information about "no given file". Dont produce overheads. Maybe you take a look into your controller. If the data is that different (AJAXPOST or POST) so create two PHP-Actions. One AJAX handler and one POST handler. In that case you can handle the different post-datas.

This information will help you:
[How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

You need to use Plugins like [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/), or [Valums](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader) to make that work. Just read a bit more about AJAX and Filepost.

Comment: Thanks for referencies. But my task is simple and I dont want to use plugins for such simple task.

Comment: Handling files with AJAX is not that simple. It comes up with a lot of problems due to different clients, hugh files and all that stuff. (As you can see in your "simple"-Error here =) In your case, no file is selected so there is no need to send information about "no given file". Dont produce overheads. Maybe you take a look into your controller. If the data is that different (AJAXPOST or POST) so create two PHP-Actions. One AJAX handler and one POST handler. In that case you can handle the different post-datas. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for advices. I think it is better don't send information about "no given file".

Answer (score 0):

you could check for `$_FILES['myfile']['error']` and `$_FILES['myfile']['size']` and return an array of your choice as result. if $_FILES['myfile']['error'] is equal to zero then there is no error. you can find more details on php.net

Comment: I don't need any action in server. My $_FILES is empty array when I send 'empty file' with ajax. But I need info in $_FILES. The problem is in FormData and Ajax only.